# How to add correct file path in html

Tags: html, css, filepath

All I want to do is add a relative file path for a .css file, into a html form. I've tried every permutation I can think of and it's still not finding it. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

I've added a screenshot, to show where both the html and css files are in the structure, and the file path I'm using in the html.

Can someone please help?

[image: Screenshot of file structure in IntelliJ]

Comment: This is, I think, very much a question about how to access static files with dealing with Java Servelets and whatever web server you are using. Someone with Java expertise might be able to answer based on the information you've provided, but it is beyond me. You really should update the question with that above information and make it clear that this Java problem and not a simple directory structure problem.

Comment: Aside: The HTML 4.0 Transitional doctype (a) triggers quirks mode and (b) was designed as a mid-point from the transition from HTML 3.2 to HTML 4.0 Strict in 1998! I really wouldn't recommend using it 23 years later! We have HTML 5 now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "../" or "./" in all paths of *src* or *href* attributes then try to use the

```
<base href="http://example.com">
```

in your <head>

Answer (score -2):

Sorry my previous answer didn't work. But I did realize what was going wrong. You had `REL=STYLESHEET` but it should be `REL="STYLESHEET"`

Comment: No. Link uses `href`. It is Script and Img that use `src`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. still not made any difference though